# Guidelines when editing questions

Tags: discussion, edits

I have been editing Stack Overflow posts for awhile, and the majority of my edits seem to get accepted, but I wanted to take a step back for a second and see how the community thinks questions should be edited.

#### Most of my edits fall under:

- Fixing spelling/grammar
- Fixing syntax indentation
- And adding tags to posts

## I think these can be broken into two categories:

#### No Duh Edits

- Spelling and Grammar
- Improper capitalization
- Unhighlighted code
- A whole code block starting with unnecessary indentation

#### Risky Edits

- Changing code indentation from tab/4 spaces to 2 spaces
- Combining sentences to make them more readable
- Adding tags

I am fine making no duh edits, but when it comes to more risky edits I try and avoid them, but an argument can be made for them. With tab/4 space indentation code blocks become long, and many do not fit into the web page without scrollbars. Fixing indentation seems like it could be a good thing, but you are also deviating from the original code, and the example no longer matches the real thing.

Adding tags also seems like it could be a good thing, but the person asking the question may have only intended it to have that one tag. For example, I was editing a MySQL question, and I noticed the code was written in PHP, so I added the PHP tag. While the issue itself is with MySQL, I figured PHP programmers might be familiar with the error since there is overlap.

Lastly, how full proof is the approval process. If there is an edit I am not sure about, can I expect the approval process to protect the question from being altered too much? Perhaps I am overthinking this, but I would love to know how other people edit. Cheers.

Comment: You are not overthinking enough if you haven't run a search on all these repeated notes